# Running Jekyll Blog on Windows Hosts at http://127.0.0.1:4000C:/Program Files/Git/blog/

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I created a new blog using Jekyll and would like to host it on GitHub Pages. Before I push the changes, I want to preview the site locally on a Windows 10 box. The problem is Jekyll is hosting index.html under the URL *http://127.0.0.1:4000C:/Program Files/Git/blog/* and the assets under *http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets*. For some reason it is appending **C:/Program Files/Git** to the path for index.html.

I expect it to host under *http://127.0.0.1:4000/blog*. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

See the Bash output below. Notice the server address and the errors attempting to download assets.

[image: Bash Output]

**_config.yml**

```
title: Testing 123
email: testing123@gmail.com
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Blog Description
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: testing123
github_username:  testing123
show_downloads: false
google_analytics: UA-00000000-1
repository: joebuschmann/joebuschmann.github.io

# Build settings
theme: jekyll-theme-minimal
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
```

**Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
#gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0.0"
# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
#gem "minima", "~> 2.5"
# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
end

# Windows and JRuby does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# and associated library.
install_if -> { RUBY_PLATFORM =~ %r!mingw|mswin|java! } do
  gem "tzinfo", "~> 1.2"
  gem "tzinfo-data"
end

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :install_if => Gem.win_platform?
```

Comment: Try setting the `baseurl` in the config file and build on the terminal with just `bundle exec jekyll serve`..

Comment: Setting the `baseurl` didn't work. Ultimately, I gave up on Jekyll and migrated to Hugo.